# Using EclipseLink JPA to bind Strings larger than 255 characters

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I inherited a project which uses EclipseLink JPA to persist objects into any SQL database. Currently it comes with a local Derby DB distribution. During some tests I found out that the program will throw the following exception:

> 012-08-03 10:21:11.357--UnitOfWork(32349505)--Exception
>   [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal
>   Exception: java.sql.SQLDataException: A truncation error was
>   encountered trying to shrink VARCHAR 'some necessarily really long text' to length 255. Error Code: 20000

Obviously VARCHAR isn't (usually) suitable for storing Strings larger than 255 characters yet I didn't find the code fragment where the objects variable is explicitely assigned to a VARCHAR field. I understand that JPA or EclipseLink automatically assigns this for you, so my question, where I couldn't find a simple answer yet, is:

How can I make sure that EclipseLink / JPA stores Strings larger than 255 characters?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to annotate the property so it gets persisted as `Clob`. Use `@Lob`; for `String`s this will default to `Clob`. See [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Lob) for the documentation. Of course you need to make sure that the database column type is correct (i.e. not `VARCHAR`) if you create the database manually.

Answer (score 2):

In many enviroments @Column of type String has limit larger than 255, for example to 4kB.
You need use 'length' to change default 255

@Column(length=1024)

String sample;

Answer (score 1):

I show you data type that to bind String larger than 255 characters. See this;

Java Type  -  byte[], java.lang.Byte[], java.sql.Clob

Java DB, Derby, CloudScape - CLOB(64000)

Oracle - LONG

DB2 - CLOB(64000)

Sybase - TEXT

MSSQL - TEXT

MySQL - TEXT(64000)